# webpack javascript in one line

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am running an Angular 4 project with Webpack 2.4.

For some reason, some of the third party Javascript plugins files are being modified after compilation, and they are shown in the browser's debugger as a very long, one line string:

[image: Browser's debugger]

This is very inconvenient because I can't use Chrome / FF debugger, as I am unable to set up any breakpoint in there.

Following some of the already posted questions in this site and many others, I extracted the `webpack.config.js` file by executing `ng eject`

The section where the `js` files are imported look as follows:

```
{
    ...        
    "scripts": [
        ...
        "script-loader!./node_modules/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js",
        ...
    ],
    "styles": [
        ...
    ]
},
"output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
}
```

The file `handsontable.full.js` does not look like that in my project's folder. It seems to be pretty structured. It seems to suffer some kind of modification when the application is built and served.

More puzzling, many other files in the `node_modules` folder do not have the same problem.

Now, I tried to tweak the `webpack.config.js`, as suggested in many forums, specifically `SourceMapDevToolPlugin`, but with very little luck.

So, several questions arise here:

1. What is happening here? The transformed file doesn't seem to be a minified file, or a hashed file... What is it?
2. How can I prevent this from happening, so I can set up breakpoints in that file and use the browser's debugger for tracing, var inspect, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `devtool:` property in the Webpack config object. If it's set to `eval`, `cheap-eval-source-map` (or something like it, don't remember all the eval options), try changing it to `source-map` or `cheap-source-map`.

Full list of options here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/